# Set product attribute "comment" from backend

Tags: layout, event-observer, product-attribute, adminhtml

No time for coding actually, so I just want to ask if maybe someone already has a working solution (w/o rewrites) :)

I just want to add a text input field to "edit product attribute" page, that show "comment" value for this attribute (that is displayed below input ... like char limits for meta-attributes).

Thanks.

<sup>(I'd use it for M1 & M2, but one solution would be fine)</sup>